# layout_alignParentBottom not working as expected

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to get a couple of buttons to attach to the bottom of the screen.
For some reason they are attaching themselves to the previous view:

[image]

As you can see the buttons are overwriting the previous view.

This is the layout I use:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:text_field_element="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:button_element="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/data_entry"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
    >
        <com.applicat.meuchedet.views.TextFieldElement
            android:id="@+id/dental_clinics_search_screen_clinic_type_selector"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            text_field_element:prompt="@string/dental_clinic_search_screen_dental_clinic_type_prompt"
            text_field_element:initial_text="@string/dental_clinic_type_initial"
            text_field_element:cursor_visible="false"
            />
        <include
            layout="@layout/separator_element"
            />
        <com.applicat.meuchedet.views.LocationSelector
            android:id="@+id/dental_clinics_location_selector"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
        <include
            layout="@layout/separator_element"
            />
        <com.applicat.meuchedet.views.TimeSelector
            android:id="@+id/dental_clinics_time_selector"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
        <include
            layout="@layout/separator_element"
            />


    </LinearLayout>


        <com.applicat.meuchedet.views.ButtonElement
            android:id="@+id/dental_clinics_search_screen_search_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            button_element:margin_bottom="10"
            />
        <com.applicat.meuchedet.views.ClearButtonElement
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/dental_clinics_search_screen_search_button"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            button_element:margin_bottom="10"
            />


</RelativeLayout>
```

separator_element.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
    android:src="@drawable/form_separator"
    >
</ImageView>
```

============================================================================

Edit:

So, it seems that the problem is caused by the fact that the view is put into a ScrollView. We need the ScrollView due to the possibility of small screens.
For some reason it sets the size wrong or something and puts the buttons just below the fields instead of at the very bottom.

Comment: If you use the Android default Button instead of `com.applicat.meuchedet.views.ButtonElement` does it work, or does it still have the same problem?

Comment: Above what @RocketSpock has to suggest, have you checked it out on different screen sizes? What if you don't specify a 'button_element:margin_bottom'?

Comment: @RocketSpock Tried it will the default button and the result was the same.

Comment: would you post the layout for `separator_element`.  When I use just Android system components (EditText, Button, etc.) it is drawn correctly.

Comment: @RocketSpock Added above

Comment: Did you override all the three constructors in your "com.applicat.meuchedet.views.ClearButtonElement" class?

Comment: @Abhishek Shukla We have only overriden the 2-parameter constructor:public ClearButtonElement(final Context context, AttributeSet attrs)

Comment: Override them all, and see the magic

Comment: @RocketSpock  Added some more info in edit